# Ideal sheaf of subvariety of projective space

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X\subset \mathbb{P}^n$ be a subvariety (reduced and irreducible). If $S$ is the polynomial ring on projective space and $I\subset S$ is the ideal defining $X$, is the ideal sheaf of $X$ given by $\tilde{I}$?

If not, how is the ideal sheaf related to $\tilde{I}$?

Comment: What do you mean by "the sheafification of $I$"?

Comment: @EricWofsey I edited the statement to address your question. I mean the coherent sheaf associated to $I$.

Comment: Some related references are in R. Hartshorne's book Algebraic Geometry. Particularly Prop. II.5.9 (quasi-coherent sheaves of ideals on a scheme X are closed subschemes). Cor. II.5.16 and Ex.II.5.10 gives you the relation to ideals you are looking for.

Comment: The grand conclusion being that there is a 1-1 correspondence between saturated ideals of S and closed subschemes of Proj(S).